# Passing selected option from select box to a different php file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Before diving into code, I'm looking for some good suggestions on how I might go about passing a selected option from a select box to a different php file and then running a specific mySQL query based on the passed option (which option the user selects). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest example to jquery ajax.

Let you aim is to get the cities in a country on select of a country from selectbox, and display the result in a div.

### HTML

1. download and include "jquery" to your html page.
2. let this is your selectbox.

   < select name="country" id="country">

   < option value="1">Country1< /option>

   < option value="2">Country2< /option>

   < /select>
3. Div to display result

   < div id="city">< /div>

You should correct the spaces in html code, I put spaces in tags because stackoverflow not showing html code (or I don't know how to put).

### Jquery

```
<script>
$('#country').live('change', function() {
    $.post("ajax.php",{country_value: $(this).val()},
    function(data){
        $("#city").html(data.cities);
    },"json");
});
</script>
```

### PHP

file >> ajax.php

```
$country_value = $_POST['country_value'];
$sql = "SELECT `city_name` from `city` WHERE `country_value` = $country_value";
$data = mysql_query($sql);
$output = "";
if($data && mysql_num_rows($data)>0)
{
    while($cities = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    { $output .= $cities['city_name'] .","; }
}
echo json_encode(array("cities"=>$output));
```

Comment: How would your code change if you wanted to populate multiple textboxes based on elements of the array being sent from json_encode. I'm assuming $("#city").html(data.cities); would change? I have the following code so far: $array = array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>
$textboxValue2,'third'=>$textboxValue3,'fourth'=>
$textboxValue4,'fifth'=>$textboxValue5,'sixth'=>
$textboxValue6);
echo json_encode($array);

Comment: yes you are right!. and then in the jquery script $("#idtextbox1").html(data.first);  $("#idtextbox2").html(data.second); and so on..

Comment: When you do function(data) inside the JQuery block where does the word data come from? Is it coming from the $data in the PHP block or is this just a random made up word?

Comment: its the data returned after execution, please refer to [Jquery post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: I have followed your code for the most part, but my textboxes aren't populating. I have taken the relevant portions of code from my two files and put them into a pastebin file. Any ideas why the textboxes aren't populating? http://pastebin.com/18GMiYSc

Comment: to test if the php code returns any error/data you have to set a blank div with an id suppose**< div id="display_whats_going_on" >** then change the jquery $post(); function to `$.post("ajax.php",{country_value: $(this).val()},function(data){$("#display_whats_going_on").html(data);});` now you can see the result coming from the php code.

Comment: I tried using a div tag for data.first and just the word data, but nothing showed up. I also tried using a textbox, but nothing showed up in that either. So I'm assuming nothing is being sent. Any ideas?

Comment: are you removed `},"json");` area?

Comment: Are you asking did I remove what you typed above for the div comment code above?

Comment: I have seen your `pastebin.com/18GMiYSc` code, I don't know why you placed the `header()` code, I think no need of that code. also you have to declare the `$queryResult = array();` before while because sometimes the array cannot be accessed. also another ajax metod you should check these too [example1](http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/), [example2](http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/jquery-php-ajax-json/#.UFqN4LIgfIc), [example3](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/#.UFqN4LIgfIc)

Comment: I'm going to leave the header line in unless you're saying it's causing a problem because I believe I got recommended to add it in from another Stack Overflow question. I went ahead and declared the array, but the textboxes are still not being populated.

Comment: I eventually got it working using some of your code, but in my situation it didn't work unless $country_value = $_POST['country_value']; changed to $country_value = $_POST["country_value"];

Comment: Since I have accepted the answer, I removed the Pastebin link.